# Grid View image load on scroll and image cache

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, universal-image-loader

I want to load the `Async` image loading for grid view. The image loading should be `Async` and should only when grid view scrolled. And when scroll up the image should be loaded from cache. Simply i need a loading style just like fb,pinterest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact requirement in serviced by `Android Universal Image Loader Library`. Check out the github repository [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

There is a sample code given here which shows the working of the loader for a grid layout.

Hopefully this will serve your need.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jake Wharton's Picasso Library. (A Perfect ImageLoading Library form the developer of ActionBarSherlock)

A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android.

Images add much-needed context and visual flair to Android applications. Picasso allows for hassle-free image loading in your application—often in one line of code!

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled automatically by Picasso:

Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter. Complex image transformations with minimal memory use. Automatic memory and disk caching.

[Picasso Jake Wharton's Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: is there any image cache library , i have a array of bitmaps i have to cache in disc?..